# Do I need to re-report a bug?

Tags: discussion

A while ago, [I reported a bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134670/37848) in Mathematica and I got an [official response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190119/37848) which confirmed its existence and promised to take care of it.

Now that the new version of Mathematica (12.0) has been released, I tested my code again and apparently, the bug is still there. Although it's been a while since my report and I think they've had enough time to deal with this bug.

So what should be done in this kind of situation?

Comment: Wolfram, Inc. often does not fix bugs quickly.  I know no solution except to wait.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to the main site.

Comment: I don't feel as though it would necessarily be a bad thing to re-report, particularly if it's a burning issue for you. Although I wouldn't expect it to speed anything up...

Comment: I have been re-reporting bugs every time a new version comes out. I wouldn't assume that they review bug reports about old versions.